# Fact regarding algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Suppose $B$ is $A$-algebra. That means there exists a structural ring homomorphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ which gives rise to the $A$-module structure of $B$. Now I found this result: $B$ is finite $A$-algebra $\iff$ $B$ is finite type $A$-algebra and $B$ is integral over $A$. Shouldn't it be $B$ is integral over $f(A)$ as integrality is defined on subrings and $A$ may not be a subring of $B$ ?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structural homomorphism $f : A \to B$ is meant to be indicative of the "subring structure" of $A \subset B$. Indeed, when $A$ is a subring of $B$ (in the sense you are familiar with), then the inclusion
$$A \hookrightarrow B$$
gives the $A$-algebra structure of $B$. In other words, this map is a formal way of expressing that $A$ is a subring of $B$, and is more indicative of the general situation where this structural map need not be injective.